# Merging non-git folder with git folder

Tags: git, merge, branch

Backstory:

Basically, I was asked to make some significant changes to a project.  I used git clone to start my involvement.  I created a new folder and copy pasted all of the code in the main project dir over to the new folder.  This new folder did not track my changes (obviously).

I have an up to date folder of the website and a folder that is not up to date but has all of my changes.  Is there anyway to merge these folders that preserves the changes I made and the changes others made?

I worry that if I update the main project folder I could accidentally overwrite their changes without realizing it.

I was thinking about using [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Clone the original repository.

  ```
  git clone $url repo
  cd repo
  ```
- Checkout the commit you copied when you started your work
- Create a new branch at this point

  ```
   git checkout -b my_work $sha1
  ```
- Add your work as a new commit at the new branch

  ```
  cp -r /path/to/untracked/dir .
  git add .
  git commit -am 'fixed nasty bug'
  ```
- optional have a look at your changes

  ```
  git show
  ```
- checkout the main branch

  ```
  git checkout master
  ```
- merge you new branch into the main branch

  ```
  git merge my_branch
  ```
- resolve any conflict that might occur

  ```
  git mergetool -t meld
  ```

(Instead of `meld` you can use any other tool you like. I would suggest `kdiff3`.)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  I'll try this right away.  I have two questions though.  1) What is the best way to view the commit history so I can find my starting point and 2) what does the $sha1 argument mean?

Comment: After the clone do `git log` or `gitk`. This will show you the history of the current branch. Each commit is identified by a 40 digit sha1 commit id. If you are able to find the correct commit use its id as "$sha1". - Try to remember when you copied your code and from which branch. Finding the correct commit is crucial. - Use the `git show` step above to verify, that the shown changes are indeed the one done by you. If there are also other changes, you most probably picked the wrong commit.